# Crontab ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, cron, ubuntu-20.04, python-venv

I have prepared a py Script to update my Django database and upload a file to gdrive once a day. Trying to use Crontab along with python to run the py script.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

I have already installed googleapiclient module.
There is no error while running the same script in venv (virtual environment).

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder1/folder11/script2.py
```

How to access the already installed module inside crontab..?

Answer (score 2):

Enable your virtual environment as following:

```
. /path/to/virtualenv/python/bin/activate
```

Then with your virtual environment enabled type the following command:

```
which python
# /home/myuser/.virtual-envs/yourvirtuaenv/bin/python
# example of output of which python
```

That will give you back the path that you can use in your crontab.

Then you can use something like the following:

```
0 2 * * * /home/myuser/.virtual-envs/yourvirtuaenv/bin/python /home/user/folder1/folder11/script2.py
```

Happy coding.